# Send a message to wildfly JMS message queue using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jms, wildfly

My questions is related to [an older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493732/spring-boot-reading-spring-jms-jndi-name-property-from-application-properties-f/59296312#59296312).

I am trying to publish a message to a Wildfly JMS queue. Right now the queues and the app run on the same JBoss container. I am trying to create a new Spring Boot app that can publish messages to the existing queues from another container. Since Wildfly is old I am not finding much help online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All JMS clients (including Spring JMS) need basic things like JNDI context properties, admin object names, etc. You can refer to the [Wildfly Hello World JMS Quickstart](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/master/helloworld-jms/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/jms/HelloWorldJMSClient.java) for these details and then plug them in to your Spring Boot application. The actual names of the admin objects (i.e. connection factory, queue, etc.) will, of course, vary based on your particular configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Justin. I tried to start from scratch. Just a simple maven project with one class to test the JMS message publishing. Running into a lot of dependency issues.  I added the wildfly jms bom as a dependency. I was under the impression that it would pull in all the required dependencies.Looks like that is not the case.

Comment: Please ignore my comment above. I found the rght branch version and it worked. Thanks a ton for your help Justin!!!